# Is it possible to force node.js to read files in the same order windows/linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script in node.js which read files as they are found in a folder on the OS.

The order of the files is important in my case (Linux order).

I get inconsistent results when running the node.js because on the way files are ordered differently between Windows and Linux.

I would like to know if there is a way to force a order at node.js global level (I am aware I sort programmatically in my script).

Examples of result I get now:

LINUX:

```
BOMItem.stories.storyshot
BOMItem.stories.storyshot
BOMItem.stories.storyshot
BillOfMaterialsTab.stories.storyshot
```

WIN:

```
BillOfMaterialsTab.stories.storyshot
BOMItem.stories.storyshot
BOMItem.stories.storyshot
BOMItem.stories.storyshot
```

Comment: And which order is correct/desired?

Comment: And how do you sort? i.e. where is the code?

Comment: I can force some sorting at script level, my question instead if it is possible to change it at a global level in node

Comment: Ok so is this list as a result of sorting or using node to walk the file tree?

Comment: @GibboK 

"is it possible to change at a global in node" - no. Node's dir function reports file in order of system API. And so it can be different on different platforms, even depends on order of file creation.

Comment: correct, the script which run a file tree is from a third party, so I cannot really change it, instead I would like to force this behavior on my enviroment

Comment: @c-smile is correct. The order of the files depend on the OS. One thing I'm aware of in terms of file naming differences between windows and unix is that windows files are case insensitive, whereas other Unix's take the casing of the file names into consideration. So this problem might be best solved by sorting the files rather than depending on the filesystem to be consistent on both OS's

Comment: My specific issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the directory listing isn't up to your application, it's up to the OS to decide how to sort.

If you need that listing to be deterministically sorted, you must do so in your application.

To do this globally requires some nasty monkey patching... something you should avoid as it may create unintended side effects and compatibility problems with future versions of Node.